# Page loads differently when refreshing vs. following URL

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the weirdest problem. My page style is not consistent in Google Chrome:

- when I simply visit the URL below or click a link to get there, everything is fine
- then, when I refresh the page, every once in a while the layout of the buttons gets messed up

To be clear: this is not a cache issue: it's not only happening after uploading a new file or anything. I guess it's got something to do with the order in which files get loaded, but I'm not sure as to what could cause this.

Here's a messed up screenshot: http://www.jurgenvisser.nl/ThemeForest/Emerald/messed_up.png

A working example can be found here: http://www.jurgenvisser.nl/ThemeForest/Emerald/?p=features/buttons

I hope there's someone who can help me out here.

Comment: I see the issue happening as well, but I'm not convinced it's not a cache issue. When I have my Chrome dev tools open, I see the issue even when visiting the page normally. I have my dev tools set to always load from server (ie. no cache). Why this is happening, I really have no clue, but don't rule out the cache yet.

Comment: FYI: Refresh in many browsers constitutes a *post* and is *not* the same thing as re-visiting the page.

Comment: Have you tried validating the page for your doctype of choice?

Comment: Adding a `display:inline-block` to `a.button` seems to solve the problem, but has some side-effect due to your current code, which is not very 'standard'.

Answer (score 1):

The exact issue, I have no idea. But they way you've coded those button is... less than the standard.

I suggest you try the '[slidingdoors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)' technique as it is much more reliable if you need to use images.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you are using block level elements inside your anchors without ever setting the anchors themselves to display block.  As [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A) anchor tags should not contain block levels.  That being said you have two options:  1)  Make the 's block elements (display:block), or 2) Make the 's inside the 's inline elements (display:inline);

**Edit:**
You can alternatively try using an HTML5 doctype as block level elements ARE legal inside  using that doctype.  Just replace your current doctype with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Thank you. The problem with making the anchor a block element is I want it to adjust its width to the text, but there are occurrences where I don't want to float the button.

Comment: A block-level element in the html-spec is different from css. Setting display:block on an inline element, will only change the appearance to look like a block element, but it's still an inline one, according to the spec. Secondly, adding the doctype doesn't change how browsers handle the page. The only thing that changes is that validators will use the html5 spec, and not show you a validation-error. Still, it might be better for Jurgen to use span elements instead of div's inside the anchor.